# how to code previous and next button in pagination in php

Tags: php

I already coded the pagination for my page, and it works well, but I could not figure out the way for the next and previous button If the page greater than 10 pages. Here is my code.

```html
<?php
include '../controllers/config.php';

/// pagination
$numberpage = 5;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;

$countSql = $sqlCon->prepare("select COUNT(id) from posts ");
$countSql->execute();
$row = $countSql->fetch();
$numberRecodes = $row[0];

$numberLink = ceil($numberRecodes / $numberpage);

$start = $page * $numberpage;
if (!$page) {
    $page = 0;
}

// select all data in table posts
$selectQuery = "select posts.category, posts.title, posts.create_date from posts limit $start, $numberpage";
$stmtArticle = $sqlCon->prepare($selectQuery);
$stmtArticle->execute();
$articleList = $stmtArticle->fetchAll();
$stmtArticle->closeCursor();
?>
```

this is the numbers link that can click on for pagination. How can I make a next and previous button in this block? Can you guys help me a little bit? So that is mean If I have 50 recodes in my database table, and divide by 5 so I will have 10 pages, and I want If the page more than 5 and then the button text will appear and I just click next for the rest of the number behind page 5. The same thing with the previous button.

```html
<div class="link-numbers">
   <?php
       for ($i = 0; $i < $numberLink; $i++) {
            $y = $i + 1;
         echo '<a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $y . '</a>';
         }
       ?>

</div>
```

Maybe something like this one:

[image for pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNnn0.jpg)

thank you so much.